# <li> takes a row completely in Firefox and IE, but works perfectly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, html-lists

`<li>` tag works perfectly in google chrome, but not in Firefox and IE.

Below is my html code.

```
<div class = "sec2_card_info sec2_card_info1">
    <ul class = "bullet_list">
         <li><a href = "#"><p>Statement made by Hon. Mangala Samaraweera, in Response to Hon. Nimal Siripala De Silva</p></a></li>
         <li><a href = "#"><p>May Rally in Sri Lanka</p></a></li>
         <li><a href = "#"><p>Hon. Mangala Samaraweera visit to China</p></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Output in Google Chrome: Works Perfectly [image]

In Firefox and IE, `<li>` takes a row completely and the output is as belows.

[image]

I haven't use too much CSS rather than padding-left and font-size. How to fix this?

Comment: have you heard or tried [this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp) ?

Comment: @renmark Haven't tried, what properties should I use?

Comment: Try making your paragraphs surround your anchors.

Comment: @AndyHoffman Thanks, it worked. Make this an answer, so others can see.

Comment: I migrated my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your paragraph tag should *not* be a child of the anchor. Instead, try this:

```
<li><p><a href="#">May Rally in Sri Lanka</a></p></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you are specified width in parent div class ='sec2_card_info sec2_card_info1' or applying display:inline-block.

Please check whether you have added width or not. Please remove that width and apply css display:inline-block.

Comment: Remove the width, didn't work. As @AndyHoffman suggested in the comments, I surrounded the paragraphs with anchor tag and it worked